# Problem with remoteAudioUrl in call using circuit by unify

Tags: javascript, circuit-sdk

we can not listen to the conference earlier if it could.

the code fragment used is this

```html
client.addEventListener('callStatus', evt => {
  if (!call || call.callId === evt.call.callId) {
    output(`callStatus event received. reason: ${evt.reason}, state: ${evt.call.state}`);
    call = evt.call;
    convList.disabled = !call.isRemote && call.isEstablished;
    enableVideo.disabled = !(!call.isRemote && call.isEstablished);
    enableScreenShare.disabled = !(!call.isRemote && call.isEstablished);
    enableRecording.disabled = !(!call.isRemote && call.isEstablished);
    // Set local video stream
    localVideo.src = call.localVideoUrl || '';
    // Enable video checkbox
    if (call.isEstablished) {
      //remoteAudio.src = call.remoteAudioUrl.substring(5);
      remoteAudio.src = call.remoteAudioUrl;
      // Set remote video streams (up to two in this example)
      if (call.participants && call.participants.length > 0) {
        remoteVideo1.src = call.participants[0].videoUrl;
      }
      if (call.participants && call.participants.length > 1) {
        remoteVideo2.src = call.participants[1].videoUrl;
      }
    } else {
      remoteAudio.src = '';
      remoteVideo1.src = '';
      remoteVideo2.src = '';
    }
  }
});
```

We need to know if something changed in the last month since it previously works

Comment: Nothing has changed in the last couple of months. Back in May it was announced that remoteAudioUrl (and the corresponding videoUrls) are being deprecated. You should use remoteAudioStream now.

But having said that, the remoteAudioUrl is still working now. I just tested the direct call and group call examples at https://plnkr.co/edit/STMZA8?p=preview and https://github.com/circuit/circuit-sdk/blob/master/examples/js/groupcall.html#L200. Both work. The direct call still uses the url whereas the group call example uses remoteAudioStream.

Do you get a remoteAudioUrl at all?

Comment: you would not have an example in javascript without using framework like vue.js or angular.js

Comment: "remoteAudioStream":{}, the is object is empty

"remoteAudioDisabled":false,
"remoteAudioStream":{},
"remoteAudioUrl":"blob:https://arsacademia.com/76bcd79a-8bc3-4a57-8857-c0f32e53903a",
"remotelyMuted":true,
"remoteVideoDisabled":false,

Comment: The groupCall example listed above in the github link is plain javascript, no vue or angular. As mentioned this group call example already uses the new remoteAudioStream, but you can easily change that line to set the src attribute to remoteAudioUrl instead of the srcObject to remoteAudioStream. The remoteAudioStream should be a valid stream object and the remoteAudioUrl should be a blob.

Comment: Roger
we can not listen to the audio of the conference when previously this worked in sandbox

we are testing here 

https://arsacademia.com/academia/mod/circuit/circuit-sdk/dialout.php?nombre=English%20Life

Comment: we use the github example that you gave us with our credentials and we can not hear.                                                  https://arsacademia.com/academia/mod/circuit/circuit-sdk/testing.html

We believe that you have some problem with the United States Tenant

Comment: Ok after looking at your code and testing this on a production I got to the bottom of it. Circuit added a feature to join conferences muted by default which is on by default. Just turned that off for your tenant, can you check now? An alternative would be to unmute yourself right after starting (or joining) the conference.      Note: When running your code I observed throttle warnings which means too many API calls are made in a short time (a loop). This is probably caused by the getUsersById in the conversationInjector. You should try to cache the users in your app and only fetch new users.

Comment: Also, this setting can be changed by a tenant admin in Administration>Conferences.

Comment: We just realized this by reviewing the call object.
thank you very much